# unable to put spy on HttpSession / Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I want partial mocking on `Httpsession` but for that i need to spy it instead of mocking it , and it's a interface I can't get without request object which is already mocked.

please help.

In another word , how can I get a object of `HttpSession` without `HttpServletRequest` object.

MORE DETAIL::

There is a servlet I want to test , servlet have session and puts  "loginBean" (which contain loged in user related info) inside session, which I have mocked already and working fine , now IN GUI level , there are 2 tab , DetailSet1 , detailsSet2 , when you enter data of DetailSet1 , it get saved in session and also does some business logic , now it comes to DetailsSet2 , you already have DetailSet1 in session , so it got all it needs , data is saved in DB.  No it's obvious I have to mock `HttpSession` because I am running unit cases from outside the container , but data which gets stored is also in `Httpsession`  , if I mock those as well , it defeats the purpose of testing. back to what I started with , I need `Httpsession` object to return mocked data for what I have it mocked for and it is suppose to act like any normal `HttpSession` object for other cases. Like , if I do session.setAttribute("name","Vivek) , then `session.getAttribute("name")` should `return "Vivek"` after that , but in case of mocked object it return `null` why? because I haven't mocked behaviour for `getAttribute("name")`. I am really sorry if I am still can't make anyone understand what I am asking for.

In simple word Partial mocking on `HttpSession`.

Comment: Describe your use case a little more. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to Partially mock HttpSession.

Comment: As I said, describe your **use case** - not what you technically want to do, but what you want to *achieve*. Are you testing? What is the larger context of your question?

Comment: Changed the Original post , please read again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok I get it. you don't really have access to the real session object and you won't do any spy. you need your home-made mock (fake):

```
public class MockHttpSession implements HttpSession {
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public Object getAttribute(String name) {
    return map.get(name);
  }

  @Override
  public void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {
    map.put(name, value);
  }


  // implement rest of the methods you will use
```

and then in your test you'll have:

```
when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(new MockHttpSession());
```

Comment: Thanks , already tried , that worked , Thank a lot @Pbielicki

Answer (score 3):

Just implement the interface HttpSession yourself (I'd name it FakeHttpSession, based on the names proposed in [Martin Fowlers bliki](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html)).

Then you create an instance and spy on it using Mockito.

Comment: Thanks Jens , looks like this might work , let me give it a try , bbl :)